# Package Initialization in Java

Tags: java, initialization

I'm building a Java package and I need some initialization code to be called in order for the package to work properly. The package is being wrapped up as a `.jar`, and I have no control over what the user will be calling when they import my package into their application. Rather than having them need to call an initialization method before they can start using my package, is there any way for this method to be called under the hood?

I'd also like to mention that the `static { }` approach won't work, as I need this code to be called one time regardless of which objects in the package are being utilized.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such method on the package level.

To achieve that you can add

```
static {
   ....
}
```

block to each of your classes and have that static block call common initializer.

For example:

```
package a.b;
class X {
  static {
     a.b.Static.init();
  }
}

class Y {
  static {
     a.b.Static.init();
  }
}

class Static {
  static void init() {
    ... my init code goes here ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, must have made the addendum to my post after you wrote up your answer. I need this code to be called one time regardless of which objects in the package are being utilized. There's really no way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

How many classes are in your `.jar`?  If there aren't many, you could have a static block in each of your classes that calls your initialization logic.  Like so:

```
static{
  MyInitializer.DoStuff();
}

class MyInitializer{
  static boolean hasInitialized = false;
  public static void DoStuff(){
    if(!hasInitialized){
      hasInitialized = true;
      //initialization logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, must have made the addendum to my post after you wrote up your answer. I need this code to be called one time regardless of which objects in the package are being utilized.

Comment: I changed the answer to only run once.

Comment: Ah, I'm surprised there's no other way to do this. Thank you for your response!